# Long File Name perevent to copy from source folder to destination on Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, copy-and-paste, path

Is there any way to copy files source folder to destination folder except move and drag. I did try to copy on my local folder but it says source path is too long. I really dont know what should I do. It is urgent. Please help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move documents from one site to another site then **Send to connection** is a way to go.

http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/how-to-configure-send-to-connections-in-sharepoint-2010/

However if you just want to save it in local drive then you can download a copy of it.In the ribbon above you can see download a copy link

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you copy files with long path names (more than 255 characters), you always face this issue. So try using 3rd party tools (such as GS Rich Copy 360)..Microsoft inbuilt file copying mechanism really fails at this..